# how to call vim function space2tab on file open and space2tab on save

Tags: vim

I am new to VIM and i found two function `Tab2Space` and `Space2Tab`. They are command in real and call another function as given this function. I can execute `:Tab2Space` and `:Space2Tab`. But I want that when I open a file to edit it automatically pass `tab2space` and `Space2Tab` before `:w`.

```
" Return indent (all whitespace at start of a line), converted from
" tabs to spaces if what = 1, or from spaces to tabs otherwise.
" When converting to tabs, result has no redundant spaces.
function! Indenting(indent, what, cols)
  let spccol = repeat(' ', a:cols)
  let result = substitute(a:indent, spccol, '\t', 'g')
  let result = substitute(result, ' \+\ze\t', '', 'g')
  if a:what == 1
    let result = substitute(result, '\t', spccol, 'g')
  endif
  return result
endfunction

" Convert whitespace used for indenting (before first non-whitespace).
" what = 0 (convert spaces to tabs), or 1 (convert tabs to spaces).
" cols = string with number of columns per tab, or empty to use 'tabstop'.
" The cursor position is restored, but the cursor will be in a different
" column when the number of characters in the indent of the line is changed.
function! IndentConvert(line1, line2, what, cols)
  let savepos = getpos('.')
  let cols = empty(a:cols) ? &tabstop : a:cols
  execute a:line1 . ',' . a:line2 . 's/^\s\+/\=Indenting(submatch(0), a:what, cols)/e'
  call histdel('search', -1)
  call setpos('.', savepos)
endfunction
command! -nargs=? -range=% Space2Tab call IndentConvert(<line1>,<line2>,0,<q-args>)
command! -nargs=? -range=% Tab2Space call IndentConvert(<line1>,<line2>,1,<q-args>)
command! -nargs=? -range=% RetabIndent call IndentConvert(<line1>,<line2>,&et,<q-args>)
```

basically i want tab for indent to edit but it converted to space before save.

Comment: "basically i want tab for indent to edit but it converted to space before save." Why do you want that? `set smarttab expandtab` should be effectively the same, without dealing with real tabs. `:help expandtab`, `:help smarttab`.

Comment: because moving cursor with `h`,`l` on tab is easy to me. with expandtab it move single space with `h` and with tab for indent it move tab `tab=4space` with `h`. and i read some where tab is not good for indentation so. it convert tab to space for vim only and save file as space for other editor. \

Comment: Moving using `h`, `l` across indentation is inefficient anyway. Using `_`, `f`, `t`, `w`... would be much better, and then you don't need to use hacks to work around non-problems. Vim is very opinionated; while you *can* make it work as you want, it is much better to adapt to *its* philosophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a file when opening you use the `BufRead` event with an `:autocmd`. Here, I'm using `*` as a pattern so that it'll apply to *all* opened files; you can adapt that to your needs.

```
:autocmd BufRead * Space2Tab
```

On writes, you want to undo the conversion, and then immediately after the write, redo it (so that you can continue editing). This set of `:autocmd`s will do that:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre * Tab2Space
:autocmd BufWritePost * Space2Tab
```

Comment: thanks it worked but when i open a file or save it need to hit enter. it shows 10 substitution on 10 lines Press Enter or type command to continue

Comment: Add a `silent`, either before the `:Tab2Space` etc. commands in the `:autocmd`, or directly inside the function, then before the `:substitute` command.

Comment: one more problem. how can i set these command to run only when file have write permission. because for `:help` files it try to write and throw errors.

Comment: The autocmds do not write the file itself, you still have to `:w` to do that. Neither should your custom commands.

Comment: Yes I understand that but when I open help `:tab2space` try to replace space with tab. And vim throw error msg because file is readonly.

Comment: Okay, that's a different problem. You can check via `if &readonly || ! &modifiable | return | endif` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: Thanks now it works as i want. learning vim is real FUN. thanks

Comment: can you please share your `.vimrc` so i can adopt some more features and learn some thing new.